# rfkill block wifi doesn't persist after a reboot

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, ifconfig, rfkill

So I'm trying to find a way to permanently disable and enable the wifi adapter on demand.

Now most questions regarding this here seem to have the problem of rfkill blocking their wifi by default and have to add a service to unblock it on boot, but I'm having the exact opposite issue.

If I run `rfkill block wifi`, that does indeed turn off the wifi. Then I reboot the system, and the wifi is up again automatically (wlan0 again listed in ifconfig).

I'd expect some service to be re-enabling it on boot, maybe something networkmanager related perhaps.

If I list all the services that have rfkill somewhere I can only find two:

```
ubuntu@pi:/lib/systemd/system$ grep -r "rfkill" .
./systemd-rfkill.service:Documentation=man:systemd-rfkill.service(8)
./systemd-rfkill.service:RequiresMountsFor=/var/lib/systemd/rfkill
./systemd-rfkill.service:BindsTo=sys-devices-virtual-misc-rfkill.device
./systemd-rfkill.service:After=sys-devices-virtual-misc-rfkill.device systemd-remount-fs.service
./systemd-rfkill.service:ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-rfkill
./systemd-rfkill.socket:Description=Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch
./systemd-rfkill.socket:Documentation=man:systemd-rfkill.socket(8)
./systemd-rfkill.socket:BindsTo=sys-devices-virtual-misc-rfkill.device
./systemd-rfkill.socket:After=sys-devices-virtual-misc-rfkill.device
./systemd-rfkill.socket:ListenSpecial=/dev/rfkill
```

Doing a `systemctl disable/enable` of both doesn't seem to change anything. The console command works regardless of them running too, so I'm not sure what's even the point of having them in the first place.

In my setup wlan0 is set as managed by the networkmanager, so I suppose it's possible that there's some service contained in it that sneakily re-enables it on boot, but I'm not sure where to start looking.

I've also attempted to add a new service that runs on boot after everything else and just does `rfkill block wifi`, but that still somehow doesn't work (if I ssh and run it then it does work though, oddly enough). Besides, that would be too late as the adapter would already be transmitting for the duration of the boot which is undesired.

Any tips on how to make this thing stay dead? This is on Lubuntu 16.04 with lxde.

Thanks :)

Comment: You've given no specifics as to your software stack. You mention a non-Ubuntu kernel, but which, and which release of Lubuntu was glued to your non-Ubuntu base?  Your question maybe better suited to SE *Unix & Linux* or the *Raspberry pi* sister sites given you're not using Ubuntu/Lubuntu as I read your description.

Comment: I am using Lubuntu as the file system part of the system, the kernel is irrelevant for this case but I figured it might help in some way. I'll update the description to remove that since I see it's misleading. As there isn't a asklubuntu.com I still think this belongs here.

I'm not sure what you mean by software stack? There's nothing out of the ordinary involved here, just bash, rfkill and the network manager.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: LXDE/Lubuntu reached EOL on April 30, 2019 (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/, see https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ and you'll note 18.04 is EOL now too) as being a *flavor* it came with only 3 years of supported life.  Lubuntu is LXQt only now, but yes Lubuntu is on-topic on this site, but only supported releases of Lubuntu (the oldest supported release is Lubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Comment: As for this site, you can see the Lubuntu 16.04 question discussed at https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18783/has-lubuntu-16-04-lts-reached-end-of-public-support which was a little under two years ago now... though flavors are now moot for 16.04 as all of 16.04 is now off-topic here (unsupported as of April 30, 2021 as now ESM support only).

Comment: You could've just said "gtfo with your old shite". I get it, you don't intend to help in the slightest. You don't have to phrase it in the most roundabout bureaucratic way possible.